# Question blocking too tight?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I've recently clicked on "Ask question" on Security SE, not to ask a question but to check the mini-faq on the right, and noticed I was about to be blocked.

So I've checked my previous questions and I only have one question, which was indeed a duplicate, however it is not completely the lazy question (and it was actually upvoted twice), I guess I've just missed the duplicate at that time.

I don't really contribute to Security SE much but I'm wondering if the criteria for blocking aren't a bit too tight?

**Edit:**

Here is the message I'm seeing:

[image]

Comment: Hi this.lau, why do you think you're about to be blocked? I don't see that on your profile at all (and I wasn't even aware that you would see such a thing on the ask page...) Could it be that what you were seeing was the notice that your question is not a good fit as it stands? This notice is intended to get you to flesh out the question a bit more, not that your account will be banned.

Comment: @AviD, I'm seeing this message only when I click on "Ask question" and it shows up right away, even before I start writing something. For information, I've added a screenshot of it to my post.

Comment: Oh, and you actually have 2 questions - one was closed and then deleted, and one was closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @RoryAlsop Network-wide features are on-topic on child metas. If the question applies to [security.se], it's on-topic on [meta.security.se], regardless of whether it applies on other SE sites (which the asker doesn't have to know).

Comment: You are not blocked, you are in danger of being blocked. The warning comes fairly early, on the assumption that it's better to warn people while they still have time to improve, rather than to suddenly tell people that they can't get in anymore. Furthermore, this warning is automatically generated; with an upvoted question (even if it's a duplicate) and an upvoted answer, you look like someone who's on the right path and just had an unlucky start, so you should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a site specific setting. Have a look at these questions over on meta.stackexchange.com:

- [Should the post-ban threshold be adjusted on MSE?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/232104/154443)
- [What should I do when I see a "question ban warning"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234042/154443)

From meta:

> ...the same algorithm that drives question and answer bans on all other Stack Exchange sites, drives question and answer bans on Meta. The difference is, the threshold is much higher on Meta. Generally, on Stack Overflow, you can expect to be banned if a small handful your posts are in the negative, if you're a new user. You get more on Meta, a lot more in my experience. But the basic algorithm is the same.

Here, we are more in the SO camp than the Meta camp - it only takes a handful of posts - however these are not actually set per site. They are general across the entire SE network (with the exceptions being the trilogy sites and Meta.SE)